# How to access the players XBOX account from your Windows 10 game app?

Tags: windows, xbox, xbox-live

We want to release a game that was previously an Android game for Windows 10 (Store / Desktop). Could you tell me how we can access the players XBOX account, see his friends and compare their scores? We also want to display their profile pictures. Sadly we don't even have an idea how the API we're looking for is called. We're confused by these "universal app" things. I saw something similar in the Minecraft app for Windows 10. Our Engine is the latest version of Unity, by the way. If informations are missing, please let me know.

All I have to know is where to find the API and it's name. A link to tutorials could be useful :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Do all games for Windows 10 need to go through ID@Xbox?**
>
> No. Only titles that want to feature Xbox Live are required to be part of ID@Xbox. Xbox Live lets you offer your players things like Gamertag identity, Achievements, Gamerscore, custom multiplayer features and more.

Join the [ID@Xbox](http://www.xbox.com/en-us/Developers/id) program.